# Need to fetch number of visits from a web page, but it was hidden in the page source

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="box_content row">
<br/>
<h3 class="nomargin">Historial del aviso</h3>
<br/>
<ul>
<li style="display:inline;margin-right:30px;">
<b>Actualizado:</b> <span>

                31 08</span> </li>
<li style="display:inline; margin-right:30px"><b>Visitas:</b> <span id="numAdvertVisits"></span></li>
<li style="display:inline; margin-right:30px"><b>Código Fincaraiz:</b> <span>  2991591</span> </li>
</ul>
<br/>
</div>
```

I got the above html element as result of my python script, however it was not showing the number of visits from the web page.

However while checking through the Inspect element, it showing the count of number of visits from a web page as below.

```
<span id="numAdvertVisits">33</span>
```

Used the below code to fetch the above html element

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/casa-en-venta/cali/ciudad_jardin-det-2991591.aspx')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
visit = soup.find('div' , 'box_content row')
print (visit)
```

How to get the Number of visits from webpage.

Comment: Maybe there is some sort of call being made asynchronously to get the page count, then the value is being loaded into the DOM separately? Check your browser dev-tools to see if any request is being made.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying this line:

```
visit = soup.find('span' , 'numAdvertVisits')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because that element is being populated by an AJAX call. The AJAX URL to that request is -https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/WebServices/Statistics.asmx/GetAdvertVisits?idAdvert=2991591&idASource=40&idType=1001

You can find those URLs using Firebug or Chrome developer tools.

Here's your updated code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/WebServices/Statistics.asmx/GetAdvertVisits?idAdvert=2991591&idASource=40&idType=1001')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
visit = soup.find('double').get_text()
print (visit)
```